# Is there any alternative to the code below for attaching files in the google spreadsheet (depreciation error (UIapp))?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets

I must admit I cannot program the solution I am seeking from scratch, usually I manipulate codes available for solving issues that I face regularly. The problem while running the code I was using

> UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.

I looked into Htmlservice documentation but did not get any idea how I could convert the entire UIapp code into functional html code. If someone has already solved file attachment problem due to deprecation (UIapp), then it would be a great help.

Or, if anyone can suggest me anything that I can use as an alternative please advise me.

```
  // upload document into google spreadsheet
  // and put link to it into current cell

  function onOpen(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var menuEntries = [];
    menuEntries.push({name: "File...", functionName: "doGet"});
    ss.addMenu("Attach ...", menuEntries);
  }

  function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("upload attachment into Google Drive");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
    var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
    var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
    form.add(formContent);  
    formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

    // these parameters need to be passed by form
    // in doPost() these cannot be found out anymore
    formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
    formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
    formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
    formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
    app.add(form);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  }

  function doPost(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.createLabel('saving...');
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('enterfolderId').createFile(fileBlob);
    var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');

    // write value into current cell
    var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
    var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
    var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
    var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
    var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
    app.add(label);
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
    app.close();
    return app;
  }
```

Comment: Approach it as though you are making an HTML form for a website. Then you use `HtmlService` to publish the HTML. Probably the easiest solution is to use a Google Form instead, and write a submission handler to handle the "form submit event". Review documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I researched the option with Google Form and Probably I will be able to do it with Google form option, the only problem I think would be how would it be possible to edit previously entered data (attachment) without repeating multiple entry for the same item?

Comment: "_how would it be possible to edit previously entered data (attachment) without repeating multiple entry for the same item_". What does this mean? is it a new question? how would one know whether an attachment had been previously entered or not? You've given no context, sample data or explanation. You're expected to "search and research **BEFORE** you ask a question. Please re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to explain just what is your programming problem.

Comment: Thank you for the Insight and apologise for the confusion created. I will re-edit my question as suggested.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue seconds ago,I am using Mac computer. I opened my APi on google chrome and unfortunately saw this 'UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.' Just a simple answer :  **SWITCH TO SAFARI** after opening my script in safari problem solved :)

Comment: That's hardly a real solution. It will absolutely fail in July: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#january_22_2019